# Is there a definitive solution for auto_complete in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm using DHH's auto_complete plugin, but am in the process of updating my dependencies on plugins to gems where feasible.  Is there a newer, gemified version of this library, or has another solution emerged as the de facto standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to jQuery autocomplete a long time ago, leaving outdated plugins in favor of unobtrusive custom javascript code.